# Using autofill framework how can i save user details that I can show as hint when user login again

Tags: android, android-autofill-manager

I am trying to save user phone, email, password, update password using android autofill framework.

I am using different fragments for all the above values. I tried to forcefully save values using autofillframework commit  method, but that doesn't work.

I am able to save username(email) and password in two consecutive fragments and autofill popup appears for this scenario but when i try to update password its doesn't save or update the password for the same.

I want to save user details for autofill hints what should i do for the same.

Comment: How were you able to save the credentials?